# Grunt, Jasmine, Yeoman

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, jasmine

I am using Yeoman to develop an AngularJs application and I am about to create a version of my application that I can ship. To make it possible I need to use grunt and run my tests first (grunt & jasmine). Every time I run my tests I get the following Error :

```
07 04 2016 14:52:38.536:ERROR [config]: Error in config file!
[ReferenceError: jasmine is not defined]
ReferenceError: jasmine is not defined
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide your config file so that we can look what's going wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define jasmine as a global variable, add it in your jshint configuration in the .jshintrc file
you may find something like this:

```
"globals": { // Globals variables.
        "jasmine": true,
        "angular": true,
        .... and so on
    },
```

Comment: try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28375214/jasmine-is-not-defined